# Getting error "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306" while connecting to mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm new to nodeJs and trying to develop my first application. I installed mysql package through npm, It got installed and I can see a successful entry of it in package.json. However, when I'm trying to connect to mysql server, it gives me this error `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306`. I searched for this issue on StackOverflow and the other users who had the very same issue got it running by adding an entry `socketPath: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'` to the configuration object. But when I added this to my configuration object, I got a new error `connect ENOENT /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`.

Here's the code by which I'm trying to connect to the server

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'blog',
    socketPath: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
});

connection.connect();
module.exports = router;
```

I'm using a Windows machine and had mysql installed before via XAMPP package. Can this be the reason behind the connection failure?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Have you started your XAMPP Server ?.

connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306 -- this error came, when you not started your XAMPP server.

Please remove socketPath & try once.

I have faced same kind of issue, when I not started the XAMPP server.

Comment: Yes, it worked for me. I connected to mysql using XAMPP application.

Comment: Yes, it worked for me. I started my XAMPP application and started mysql from there. Now I can access MySql from anywhere because I've already set it's exe path to the environment variable.

Comment: So shame that most of us just forgot to open xampp lol

Answer (score 0):

in my case is the docker network that makes the problem.

I add to my docker-compose file:
network_mode: "host"

Answer (score -3):

Check the password inserted, usually it should be "password".