# Node.js "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306" when trying to connect to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm a novice at node.js and I want to create an API which sends data to a MySQL server to store them.

I followed a youtube tutorial to create a connection with a MySQL database, also checked other tutorials just to be sure, but I always get this error message when my code tries to connect to MySQL. I used XAMPP first, and then tried downloading and using MySQL from mysql.com, but got the same error.

```
/home/broken/mysql_projekt/app.js:24
        throw err;
        ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1247:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/broken/mysql_projekt/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/broken/mysql_projekt/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/home/broken/mysql_projekt/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/broken/mysql_projekt/app.js:22:4)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true
}
```

I tried the suggested solutions at other questions but I didn't succeed.
Here's what I tried:

- Changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 in the connection configuration.
- Check in services.msc if the MySQL service is in a running state.
- Tried to add firewall rules to allow outbound and inbound access on
  port 3306.
- Create another user aside from root with a password with all
  privileges, and try to connect with that.
- Also tried to add "socketPath: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'" to my
  connection configuration, as someone in [another
  question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42899916/getting-error-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-13306-while-connecting-to-mysql)
  said that it seemed to solve other's problem, but they just got a
  different error message, just like me. (unfortunately I couldn't really understand what it does)
- Also tried on another computer, but of course the issue still
  remained.
- Tried to specify the port number to 3306 in the connection
  configuration.

Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var PORT = 3000;

var app = express();

app.listen(
    PORT,
    () => {console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`)
})

//Creating MySQL connection
var db = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : "localhost",
    user     : "user",
    password : "password"
    //socketPath: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
});

//Connecting
db.connect((err) => {
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    console.log('MySQL connected');
});
```

If someone has figured it out, could you share the solution? Thank you!